# Why does the string format returned by Range.Address(external:=True) change?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code that obtains Excel cell references as a string using

`rng.Address(External:=True, ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)`

The VBA code talks to a COM server, which needs to know what the string format is.

Unfortunately, the format seems to switch (at random?) between two cases. I don't know what is causing VBA to make this change.

The two formats are

1. `'[book]sheet'!R1C1`
2. `[book]sheet!R1C1`

That is, sometimes the book-and-sheet part has enclosing single quotes but sometimes it doesn't!

I can see these format changes within the VBA debug window by directly printing the address string.

I have experienced this on Office 2007 and 2010.

Comment: Single quotes occur when the workbook or sheet name has spaces in it.

Comment: Both are 'correct' and should be handled. The one with quotes would probably be considered the canonical form.

Comment: Of course, now I get it! Some of the tab names I used have spaces and some don't. Silly me! Thanks for the quick response :-)